# Как документировать методы Vue, если метод возвращает this?

Tags: vue.js, jsdoc

Простой пример:

```
 /**
   * Тут описание метода
   *
   * @param {number} id 
   * @return {this}
   */
  myMethod(id) {
    // ...do something

    return this;
  },
```

Варианты документации:

```
 /**
   *
   ...

   * @return {this}
   */
```

Так:

```
 /**
   *
   ...

   * @return {Object} this
   */
```

Или так:

```
 /**
   *
   ...

   * @return {Object} this - VueComponent
   */
```

Как правильно? Или как документируете вы?

Comment: А зачем? Как правило на практике редко используются компоненты, к методам которых можно/нужно обратиться извне (и один хрен среда связь с ней потеряет). Разбивка на супермелкие компоненты помогает, но это предел. Мы потихоньку переходим на react/typescript, во вью сложно за порядком следить, когда проект разрастается.

Answer (score 1):

Я не видел, чтобы была возможность в @returns указать, что возвращаться будет this метода, только тип и короткое описание. Если нужно сообщить, что функция вернёт свой this, то можно текстом указать это в описании функции.

А вообще обычно достаточно указать только тип и не более. Если к примеру Вы пишите Vector2 или Complex, Quaternion, то такие вещи разумный программист создаёт Неизменяемыми. В таком случае все операции над экземплярами этих классов всегда отдают новый объект.

Это сделано из соображения безопасности: в любой момент ссылка на объект может быть скопирована, затем в одном месте цепочка расчётов продолжается, а в другом необходимо просто хранить промежуточное значение. Сделали объект модифицируемым - одна чать программы любезно и незаметно побьёт данные в другой части. А ты бегай потом с дебаггером и соображай.

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший ответ. Да, на момент написания вопроса не совсем знал что делает `@return`. В проекте сейчас пишем `@return {Object} this - VueComponent`. Поставил `+1`.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!